# Pentaho kettle database error

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am trying to connect to the `Infobright` database from Kettle Spoon. After 15 minutes 2 seconds, I get this message:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure.

Can someone please tell me where to change the setting in the Spoon/kettle, or if there is any other issue that is giving me this error message.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this just trying to connect to the database, or running a query?  Can you explore the database in the database settings dialog?

Comment: I changed the query that runs for less than 15 minutes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, then this is what i suspected - this is actually a MySQL thing really - a limit on long running queries.

If you genuinely need longer than 15 mins you can adjust the parameter, see here:

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/eai/mysql

Answer (score 0):

In pentaho if you follow the below instructions then you can easily avoid communication link failure messages.

1)Increase the write_net to 12000 secs(2 mins)
2)Increase the heap memory size as 1024

Because pentaho is a java based language if you are running the long running queries it cant handle the huge amount data.